# Does it follow that the majority of the committee ranks A higher than C?

Tags: puzzle

> Each member of a committee ranks applicants A, B, C in some order. It is given that the majority of the committee ranks A higher than B, and also that the majority of the commitee ranks B higher than C. Does it follow that the majority of the committee ranks A higher than C?

---

This question came into one of our test. But I have some doubts in the problem. First of all, let's say a committee member ranks A higher than B, and then he ranks B higher than C. Would it be automatically counted as that he ranked A higher than C? If yes, then it is possible that the majority of the committee ranks A higher than C right? Let's say 60% of the committee ranked A higher than B, and then the same 60% ranked B higher than C, then the majority indeed ranked A higher than C. However it is not necessary. Let's say that 60% ranked A higher than B , and another 55% ranked B higher than C, but of that 55% not all of them ranked A higher than B, hence not part of that 60%, in this case it's not necessary that the majority automatically ranked A higher than C right? Am I right on this argument?

Comment: More simply, say we have exactly three voters, whose preferences are $A>B>C$ and $ B>C>A$ and $C>A>B$ respectively.    Easy to verify that the assumptions are met, but that the voters prefer $C$ to $A$.

Comment: Usually in these problems the assumptions of [Arrow's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem#:~:text=In%20its%20strongest%20and%20simplest,Unanimity%2C%20or%20weak%20Pareto%20efficiency) are meant to hold.  In particular it is assumed that each individual's preferences are transitive.  That is, if a given voter prefers $A$ to $B$ and $B$ to $C$ then that voter must prefer $A$ to $C$.  The question is whether this transitivity extends to group voting.

Comment: @lulu yes this is what I assumed as well. Assuming it's transitive, my argument, it is then correct right?

Comment: Your argument is needlessly complex, as my first comment shows.  I didn't read your argument carefully, but reading it quickly, you need to demonstrate that those numbers can be realized by a given list of (valid) voters' preferences.

Comment: So basically I need to provide an example of the scenario I'm talking about?

Comment: You need to show that the numbers you describe can be realized by a valid slate of voters' preferences.  In my first comment I gave you all the voters' preferences.  Easy to read off that $\frac 23$ prefer $A$ to $B$, $\frac 23$ prefer $B$ to $C$, but $\frac 23$ prefer $C$ to $A$, so group transitivity has failed.  You could easily modify my example if you wanted to, but a single counterexample is all that was called for.

Comment: Yes, you should provide an example to prove that the scenario is possible. Your observations are correct in identifying a problem with a certain hypothetical proof of *impossibility*, but that doesn't prove that it's possible.